# Is there a way to connect this 1.5 inch tail pipe to an older nonstandard water pipe?

Tags: plumbing

My wife and I have been renovating our powder room, primarily based around an 1932 American Standard cleat sink. I got a 17 gauge 1.5 inch brass p-trap which came with an unthreaded tailpipe. The tailpipe diameter is exactly the same size as threaded nut that was soldered onto the waste pipe, so it doesn't actually fit inside. Is there a way to connect these two pipes that doesn't involve cutting the old pipe then soldering on an expander or something?

ETA - the water pipe itself seems to be 1.5 inches, since 1.5 inch hinged wall plate fits around it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The inside of that copper pipe looks pretty filled with crud. Any possibility of replacing that pipe and drain/stopper entirely or is it somehow embedded (not familiar with the specifics of this sink) or otherwise would interfere with the aesthetic you are going for to remove it?

Comment: The pipe with all the crud is the waste water pipe, in the wall. Having just put up new dry wall and paint and everything, getting rid of that pipe is a super last resort. Cutting it back to get rid of the nut and washer could get an option. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your threaded wall pipe end may accept a 1-1/2 inch slip joint nut and washer.  If so, perhaps you could instead use a 1-1/4 drain/trap pipe, fit the end inside your wall drain pipe, and use a slip joint nut with a rubber reducing washer to make the seal at the threads around the 1-1/4 pipe.  You could always pretty-up the connection at the wall by covering it with a shiny escutcheon.

Photo of a similar situation
[image]

Product description is "1-1/2 in. x 1-1/4 in. Sink Drain Pipe Zinc Slip-Joint Nut and Rubber Reducing Washer"

Comment: The old p-trap had a 90 degree elbow which was basically a 2 inch inner diameter, and that fit the wall pipe threads. So something like this but to reduce 2 inches to 1.5 could work. But it's something to work with, thank you! I really am hoping to avoid paying a plumber to do something I feel like I should be able to do.

Comment: Please note, @Ryan, that the proper way to say "thanks" is to click the up arrow next to answers that help and the check mark next to the answer that helps the most. This is explained in the [tour].

Comment: I tried to click up and was told I needed 15 reputation to vote.